# How to remove LineRenderer starting points ?(point 0, point 1, point 2)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I created a line using LineRenderer and after a while I need to delete the starting points (point 0, point 1, point 2).I'm trying to get coroutia out of my way. But it starts to move away from the last half points and not from the initial

```
lineRenderer.positionCount = i+1;
Vector3 mPosition = new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, 15);
lineRenderer.SetPosition(i, Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mPosition));
i++;

public IEnumerator DeleteLine()
{
    int i = lineRenderer.positionCount;

    while (true)
    {

        if(i >= 0)
        {
            lineRenderer.positionCount = i;
        }
        else
        {
            lineRenderer.positionCount = 0;
            i = 0;
            StopCoroutine(_deletePosLine);
        }
        print(i);
        i--;

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Get all points of your LineRenderer with `GetPositions()` or keep the list yourself.
2. Remove the first item from the array. You can do this by allocating another array (minus one point) and copying with all items, starting from index 1. (not 0). Other alternatives exist by using Lists/Collections.
3. Then set all positions again using `SetPositions()` with the correct `positionCount` first, of course.

Or: keep track of all your points in a `Stack<Vector3>` and `Pop()` the first item, convert that to an array using `ToArray()` and use that in`SetPositions`. That might work better.

For explanation of `Stack` see for example https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-stack.

Comment: Sorry, but it didn’t work out, again the points are taken from the end

Comment: Are you still using some of your old code? Because that removes points from the end. You will really have to modify the entire point array. Out of interest I checked the `TrailRenderer`. it also supports SetPositions. So maybe that might also be a good alternative for you? It supports automatic removal of the last point by time. Maybe worth a test as well.